# How to make tkinter variables dynamically

Tags: python, tkinter

**Tkinter** dynamically made variables are not working properly in `checkbutton` of `menu`. They are displaying the wrong image as they were supposed to.

Here's my code:

```
def checkbutton(self,index,var=None):
    self.popup_menu.add_checkbutton(label=self.btns[index]['text'], command = lambda : self.menu(index) , variable=IntVar().set(1))
```

I'm using direct method `variable=IntVar().set(1)`. I aslo tried making variable like :

```
currentVar=IntVar()
currentVar.set(1)
```

But I encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `variable=IntVar().set(1)` will assign `None`, result of `set(1)` to `variable` option.  Second dynamically created variable will be garbage collected after the function completes.

You need to create an instance variable:

```
def checkbutton(self,index,var=None):
    var1 = IntVar(value=1)
    self.popup_menu.add_checkbutton(label=self.btns[index]['text'], command=lambda: self.menu(index), variable=var1)
    # self.varlist should be already created in __init__()
    self.varlist.append(var1)
```

Comment: It's just doing the work for last variable made dynamically and giving the same issue for the rest.

Comment: Then you need to use a list to store the variables.

Comment: I used list to store the variables and it worked.